# Ratio question for GRE

Tags: gre-exam

[image]

I got kind of lost in this . . . 
so you have
[(m liters)/(household)]/month and then i get lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For all $n$ households taken together, the rate at which water is needed is
$$\left(m\;\frac{\text{liters}}{\text{households}\times\text{months}}\right)\times\left(n\;\;\text{households}\right)=mn\;\frac{\text{liters}}{\text{months}}.$$
Thus, if $p$ liters is needed to last $x$ months, then 
$$p\;\;\text{liters}=\left(mn\;\frac{\text{liters}}{\text{months}}\right)\times(x\;\;\text{months}).$$
Solve for $x$.

---

This problem is an example of dimensional analysis ([Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis)).

Answer (score 3):

Since there are $n$ households, the village requires $mn$ litres of water per month. We have $p$ litres of water and $p$ litres contain $\dfrac{p}{mn}$ number of $mn$ litres which is the number of months it will last.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

"$m$ litres will last $1$ household for $1$ month"

so

"$1$ litre will last $1$ household for $1/m$ months"

so

"$p$ litres will last $1$ household for $p/m$ months"

Can you continue this process?